# Using LEADTOOLS with Java

Tags: java, leadtools-sdk

I'd like to manipulate images (e.g., change brightness, apply sepia filter) from my Java application using LEADTOOLS. The app is supposed to run on both Windows (>=7) and Mac OS.
I know that Java is not officially supported but I've seen that there are [workarounds](http://support.leadtools.com/CS/forums/8934/ShowPost.aspx) and [Android support](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/android/default.htm).

My question is: Has anybody used LEADTOOLS in recent times (with version 18 for example) in combination with Java?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd love to hear details behind choosing LEADTOOLS over a java library.  It's always easier to use a supported tool or library rather than writing a layer yourself.  Why the choice to go with LEADTOOLS?

Comment: @Kieveli: The client suggested to use LEADTOOLS. I don't know yet how firmly set he is on using that tool.

Comment: We recently released a new v19 setup for LEADTOOLS that contains Java APIs for Windows and Linux. The new Java toolkit has image processing like brightness (ContrastBrightnessIntensityCommand) and sepia (ConvertToColoredGrayCommand). It doesn't run on iOS where we still only have Objective-C libraries.